# Experience with the new Jackal PHP framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

Do you guys have any experience with the new PHP framework Jackal?

http://www.jackalphp.com

It is fresh, just-released and I was wondering if it is a good one. Can it be a substitute of frameworks like Kohana, Symphony or Zend? Well Zend has too many pre-biuld modules and functionality. Maybe a comparison with Kohana is better.

I am asking cause I am looking for a framework to use in my future projects.

Thanks

Comment: I like the logo of the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks more like a hobby product than a serious framework.

A sure sign it's not production ready is the lack of Unit-Tests. There are none in the downloadable package. Any refactorings and additions the developers apply to the framework are high risk. Without Unit-Tests, they cannot guarantee change does not break existing functionality. You do not want to build an application on top of that.

I also could not find any license information. There is none in the source code. The ToS link on the website is empty. Without a clearly defined license agreement, you are putting yourself in danger of infringing on IP.

There is also no information regarding how the development updates are handled. Can minor version upgrades contain BC breaks? And why is there no public repository when Sourceforge and Git are free to use. I couldn't find a bugtracker either.

I'd stay away from that unless they professionalize.

Comment: I have also noticed these things :( , but I was kind of hopping to get some evaluation of their concept and if it is worthy trying it. As I said I am in a process of browsing for a good PHP5 OO framework like Kohana, Yii, etc to use in my future projects.

Comment: @Yasen if you want to try it, try it in a non-critical application first. I'd definitely not use that for a public project. If you want to know more about the project, drop the developers an eMail.

Answer (score 2):

We probably released the framework a little prematurely, but we are very serious, and this is not a hobby project. We have been using it in commercial application development for over a year now.

You do raise some excellent points about things we are missing. We are currently using Assembla as a repository, but we will soon be moving to something else so that we can make it public.

Unit testing and licensing information are also on the way.

If those are the only things you are concerned about, that's great news =). Our biggest goal was to build a framework that leverages the advantages of a procedural language like PHP, speeds up development, and just makes sense. We have used a lot of frameworks before, and while they all have their strengths... none of them are what we, as developers, need in a framework. While that is a very subjective statement, I believe Jackal makes some serious improvements on other frameworks that developers will come to love.

In short, we really appreciate you taking the time to give Jackal a chance, and hope you will continue to follow our progress as we add more "professionalization" to our framework. =)

Best Regards,
Jackal Team

Comment: Good to hear that you are about to improve these things. I only looked at the code briefly to find a license and unit-tests so I cannot say if there is more I'd be concerned with.